Nombre de la tabla en consulta MYSQL con bindParam
Estoy haciendo una consulta SQL con bindParam pero no sé si se puede agregar el nombre de la tabla a través de bindParam. Si es posible, cómo se llevaría a cabo.
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM $producto WHERE Hora_Inicio BETWEEN :fechainicial AND fechafinal ORDER BY NumeroFabricacion";                
    $insert = $this->conectar->prepare($consulta);                
    //$insert->bindParam(":tabla", $producto);
    $insert->bindParam(":fechainicial", $fechainicial);                
    $insert->bindParam(":fechafinal", $fechafinal);
    $insert->execute();

Intento sustituir $producto por :tabla, pero me da un error. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

No se puede. Los parámetros son para los valores de la consulta, no para tablas o columnas. Lee la documentación sobre las consultas preparadas al respecto.

Y porqué quieres pasarlo por parámetro??

El hecho de que se puede cambiar el nombre de la tabla sugiere que tu base de datos esta mal diseñada. ¿Por qué hay tablas con la misma estructura en tu base de datos?

Lo que estás tratando de hacer no se podrá con bindParam porque bindparam trata de cambiar el nombre de un parámetro. Los nombres de tablas y columnas deben ser parte estática de la consulta SQL.
Como lo estas haciendo está bien
$producto = 'nombre_de_la_tabla';

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM $producto WHERE Hora_Inicio BETWEEN :fechainicial AND :fechafinal ORDER BY NumeroFabricacion";
$insert = $this->conectar->prepare($consulta);

$insert->bindParam(":fechainicial", $fechainicial);
$insert->bindParam(":fechafinal", $fechafinal);

$insert->execute();


Pero casi que literalmente es lo mismo que tiene el usuario!!!!!!! Según tu, $producto en el código del usuario no tiene asignado el nombre de la tabla???? Haz respondido algo que ya lo habían dicho en los comentarios y "tu código" es en 99.9999999% lo mismo que tiene el OP

entonces elimino la respuesta?

Naaaaa no soy nadie para decirte que la quites, peor si ya la aceptaron. Para la próxima intenta que tu pregunta resuelva de alguna manera el problema, A. Cedano ya lo había resuelto. Por mi parte, quería saber porqué por parámetro? Yo ya había pensado algo sobre seguridad al pasar los datos y todo esto, pero sin que el OP me diga algo no podemos asumir y responder. Salu2

@OCHOA permitir que una tabla sea pasada por parámetro es un contrasentido, y por eso las APIs que interactúan con la base de datos no lo permiten, porque hacer eso sería justo lo contrario de lo que se intenta frenar con bindParam que es la inyección SQL. Imagina que un usuario mal intencionado pueda manejar los datos de entrada y en una consulta del tipo DELETE o UPDATE cambia el nombre de una tabla por otra, provocando en desastre en los datos. Además, ¿qué sentido tiene pasar por parámetro algo que siempre es fijo como el nombre de una tabla?

Un código así no tiene ninguna utilidad, y sí muuuuchos riesgos. Y, si alguien necesita un código así, pensando que resuelve algo, lo que tiene es realmente un problema de diseño, como comentó @ThorstenKettner en la pregunta. ¿Por qué tablas con distintos nombres tienen nombres de columna que son idénticos?

Es que no se puede, pero insisto, quizás el OP quería asegurarse de pasar de una mejor manera el nombre de la tabla y no solo por el valor del POST. Algo como, mejores formas de "sanitizar" ese nombre de tabla, pero nada más
